# How to make an Oracle procedure return a cursor with multiple rows in it

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have an Oracle procedure that returns a cursor with a result set in it but with the way I have it coded it only returns the results from the last iteration of the loop that I have.

Here is an example of the code that I have

```
            create or replace PROCEDURE PROC_SB_OBTENER_STATS_TEST (FECHA_INICIO IN DATE, FECHA_FIN IN DATE, RESULTADOS OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS

            FECHAS SYS_REFCURSOR; 
            FECHA_BUSQUEDA DATE;
            BEGIN
            FECHAS := FUN_SB_OBTENER_FECHAS(FECHA_INICIO, FECHA_FIN);


            LOOP
            FETCH FECHAS
            INTO FECHA_BUSQUEDA;
            EXIT WHEN FECHAS%notfound;

            OPEN RESULTADOS FOR
            --Here I got a select where the condition uses the variable FECHA_BUSQUEDA
            END LOOP;
            CLOSE FECHAS;

            END PROC_SB_OBTENER_STATS_TEST;
```

The procedure compiles and it runs but it only returns me the cursor with the last select that it executes (if I put the dates between 10/10/12 and 12/10/12 it only returns me the result of 12/10/12).

How can I make the `OPEN FOR` add the result of a query to its current contents instead of overwriting it all and just showing me the last result?

Comment: you would need to take the query giving you the fecha_busqueda and join the resultados query to it. I.e., rather than having two separate queries that you are manually joining in PL/SQL (which is what you're doing), having one single query that does the join in SQL. That way, you can declare that as a ref cursor and simply pass it out to the calling program for it to loop through as desired.

Comment: RESULTADOS is a cursor and FECHA_BUSQUEDA is a date, I'm using the FECHA_BUSQUEDA as a value for a select query where condition and inserting it into the RESULTADOS cursor.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE DATEARRAY IS TABLE OF DATE;

create or replace PROCEDURE PROC_SB_OBTENER_STATS_TEST (FECHA_INICIO IN DATE, FECHA_FIN IN DATE, RESULTADOS OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS

        FECHAS SYS_REFCURSOR; 
        FECHA_BUSQUEDA DATEARRAY;
        BEGIN
        FECHAS := FUN_SB_OBTENER_FECHAS(FECHA_INICIO, FECHA_FIN);



        FETCH FECHAS
        BULK COLLECT INTO FECHA_BUSQUEDA;

        OPEN RESULTADOS FOR
        --Here I got a select: 
        SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE T WHERE T.DATE IN (SELECT v.COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(FECHA_BUSQUEDA) v)

        CLOSE FECHAS;

        END PROC_SB_OBTENER_STATS_TEST;
```

Comment: I didn't know of the existence of BULK COLLECT (thanks for that) but given the nature of my select query I have to select each date individually (without using 'IN (date, date, date)'), that's why I'm using the loop.